# Using z3 in an incremental way but cause more time

Tags: c++, increment, z3

I am trying to use Z3 to solve a problem with one incremental constraints by push method, for example (< Z 100), then (< Z 90), then ( < Z 80).

However, while I was using Z3 in an incremental method, I found sometimes it cost less time if we only check (< Z 80) directly (faster than time of check (< Z 80) after two incremental check in the above).

- Can you tell me the reason?
- Is it because the learned clauses is too much and make the search slow?
- Are there any strategies that can help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

**You got lucky this time**

You solved it quickly with (< Z 80) alone this time probably because your algorithm finds a very good optimum when it looks for a smaller Z, **in the particular case you used it**.

This can be purely due to your input data. To show that its better to directly look for (< Z 80) - which isn't the case, obviously - you must make many tries on many kind of input data sets.

Comment: I agree about @Yinrun being lucky. I think it is worth mentioning that 'being unlucky' corresponds to the case in which '(< Z 80)' is unsatisfiable together with the input problem instance, since it usually requires more search to prove it. However, adding upfront a satisfiable constraint of that form is in general going to lead to a (slightly) faster convergence to the same model, as opposed doing it incrementally through several intermediate steps.